# type object 'SubscriptionList' has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: django, python-3.x

Good afternoon. While trying to create an object of SubscriptionList model. I've got this error. I did a research on this topic but haven't found a relative answer.

```
Traceback:

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  41.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  68.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  88.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  213.         return super(BaseCreateView, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get
  174.         return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data())

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_context_data
  93.             kwargs['form'] = self.get_form()

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form
  44.             form_class = self.get_form_class()

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\edit.py" in get_form_class
  132.             return model_forms.modelform_factory(model, fields=self.fields)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in modelform_factory
  558.     return type(form)(class_name, (form,), form_class_attrs)

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in __new__
  261.                 apply_limit_choices_to=False,

File "D:\PyDocs\taskagain\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in fields_for_model
  144.     opts = model._meta

Exception Type: AttributeError at /blogs/1/add_to_subscription/
Exception Value: type object 'SubscriptionList' has no attribute '_meta'
```

Models

```
class SubscriptionList(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                            related_name='subscription_list')
blogs_in_subscription = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, related_name='in_subscription_lists',
                                                blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s subscription list" % self.user.username
```

Views

```
class AddBlogToSubList(CreateView):
model = SubscriptionList
fields = ['user', 'blogs_in_subscription']
template_name = 'blog/add_blog_to_sub_list.html'
success_url = reverse_lazy('blog:blog-list')

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.blogs_in_subscription = Blog.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs['blog_pk'])
    form.instance.user = self.request.user
    return super(AddBlogToSubList, self).form_valid(form)
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', BlogList.as_view(), name='blog-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/$', BlogDetail.as_view(), name='blog-detail'),
# url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/add_to_subscription/$', AddBlogToSubList.as_view(), name='add-to-subscription'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/subscriptions/$', SubscriptionList.as_view(), name='subscription-list'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/create/$', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-create'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/$', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/update/$', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post-update'),
url(r'^(?P<blog_pk>\d+)/(?P<post_pk>\d+)/delete/$', PostDelete.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
```

I'll be grateful if someone will be able to help. 
python 3.6 / django1.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a view `SubscriptionList` which is clashing with your model `SubscriptionList`. You can fix the problem by renaming the view (and updating the associated URL pattern.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time.